# nested feature in capybara 2.0+

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

i want to do something like this:

```
feature "sign-up" do
  before {visit signup_path}
  let(:submit) {"Create my account"}

  feature "with invalid information" do
    scenario "should not create a user" do
      expect {click_button submit}.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
  end

  feature "with valid information" do
    scenario "should create a user" do
      fill_in "Name",         with: "test name"
      fill_in "Email",        with: "test@test.com"
      fill_in "Password",     with: "password"
      fill_in "Confirmation", with: "password"
      expect {click_button submit}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

but when i run rspec i get

```
in `block in <top (required)>': undefined method `feature' for #<Class:0x000000039e0018> (NoMethodError)
```

if i change it a bit to look like this it works:

```
  feature "with invalid information" do
    before {visit signup_path}
    let(:submit) {"Create my account"}

    scenario "should not create a user" do
      expect {click_button submit}.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
  end

  feature "with valid information" do
    before {visit signup_path}
    let(:submit) {"Create my account"}

    scenario "should create a user" do
      fill_in "Name",         with: "test name"
      fill_in "Email",        with: "test@test.com"
      fill_in "Password",     with: "nirnir"
      fill_in "Confirmation", with: "nirnir"
      expect {click_button submit}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
```

EDIT:

plus, the following code works(describe nested inside feature) - but is it wrong in any way?

```
feature "sign-up" do
  background {visit signup_path}
  given(:submit) {"Create my account"}

  scenario "with invalid information" do
    expect {click_button submit}.not_to change(User, :count)
  end

  describe "with valid information" do
    background do
      fill_in "Name",         with: "test name"
      fill_in "Email",        with: "test@test.com"
      fill_in "Password",     with: "password"
      fill_in "Confirmation", with: "password"
    end

    scenario { expect {click_button submit}.to change(User, :count).by(1) }

    scenario "after submission" do 
      click_button submit
      page.html.should have_content("Registration successful")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT (23/01/2014):** Nested features are available since version 2.2.1. See [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/commit/61524b0fd32a1fb55b82853bdc4a0293e9fcdef0)

**EDIT (24/07/2013):** Nested features will be allowed in Capybara > 2.1.0. See [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/1113)

You can't. This is what the mantainer of the gem says about it

> I guess you could call this a limitation. `feature` can not be nested.
>   You can use either `context` or `describe` instead, but I would
>   suggest not going wild with these, it tends to make tests pretty
>   unreadable.

In some other cases the convenience of this might be argued but in this specific one you should use `scenario` instead of the nested `feature`.

Also if you want to consistent and use the new DSL everywhere, use `background` instead of `before` and `given` instead of `let`. Like this:

```
feature "sign-up" do
  background {visit signup_path}
  given(:submit) {"Create my account"}

  scenario "with invalid information" do
    expect {click_button submit}.not_to change(User, :count)
  end

  scenario "with valid information" do
    fill_in "Name",         with: "test name"
    fill_in "Email",        with: "test@test.com"
    fill_in "Password",     with: "password"
    fill_in "Confirmation", with: "password"
    expect {click_button submit}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

You have to remove the `it` because `scenario` is just an alias for `it` and you cannot nest `it` either.

Or you can always switch back to the old DSL if you find it more readable. In that case I would do something like this:

```
describe "sign-up" do
  before {visit signup_path}
  let(:submit) {"Create my account"}

  context "with invalid information" do
    it "does not create a user" do
      expect {click_button submit}.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
  end

  context "with valid information" do
    before
      fill_in "Name",         with: "test name"
      fill_in "Email",        with: "test@test.com"
      fill_in "Password",     with: "password"
      fill_in "Confirmation", with: "password"
    end
    it "creates a user" do
      expect {click_button submit}.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
  end

end
```

But as long as the spec checks what it has to check, you should be fine anyways. The rest is all a matter of style, readability and good practices, which are important but more open to discussion and disagrement. In this case the author of the gem didn't allow nested `feature`'s. Maybe for readability or maybe didn't feel it was needed or maybe didn't think about it...  If you really want to nest features you can always try to implement it and pull request it.

Comment: so instead just put inside feature describe if i must?

Comment: You are welcome. If it works, that's a good thing itself. Apart from that, you should try to stick to good practices and find a consistent style that you find readable. For example, using describe for one case  and scenario for the other is not consistent nor readable. On the other side, I like how you separated the fill_in actions in a background block. But all of this is matter of taste too. [Here](http://betterspecs.org/) you can find some recommended good practices for rspec, you can have a look and choose which ones you want to follow.

Comment: great link! i added another scenario inside the describe just to demonstrate the use i thought with the describe block. its not instead of the scenario, its to be able to nest few tests into common idea(just like nested describe block), is it wrong?

Comment: It's not wrong because your spec passes, but I PERSONALLY don't find it very readable to mix both DSL's. If I want to deeply nest specs I just use `describe`/`it`. I updated my answer again with how I would do it using the old DSL. Good luck!